# Are metacyclic $p$-groups semidirect products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product, p-groups

A group $G$ is called metacyclic if there is cyclic $N\unlhd G$ such that $G/N$ is cyclic as well. If $G$ is a metacyclic $p$-group, I know that there is a presentation

$$G\cong\langle x,y\mid\, x^{p^a}=1,\,y^{p^b}=x^{p^c},\,yxy^{-1}=x^k\rangle,$$

but is it always possible to realize $G$ as a semidirect product? Since it might make a difference: I do not care about the case $p=2$.

Comment: According to [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02234) there are nonsplit metacyclic p-groups for $p\neq 2$. You can take it from there. Maybe you also need to look into other articles referenced there. Reminder: nonsplit $\Leftrightarrow$ no semidirect product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be quite difficult to find a good link to answer this question.
Therefore I will give here the full formulation of the theorem on metacyclic $p$-groups.

**Theorem.**
For odd $p$, every metacyclic $p$-group $P$ has a presentation of
the form
$$
P =\{a,b\mid a^{p^\alpha}= b^{p^\beta}, b^{p^{\beta+\delta}}= 1,a^{-1}ba=b^{1+p^\gamma}\}
$$
where $\alpha\geq\beta\geq\gamma\geq\delta\geq0$ and
either $\gamma\geq1$ or $\beta=\gamma=\delta=0$.
Conversely, each such presentation defines a metacyclic
$p$-group of order $p^{\alpha+\beta+\delta}$,
different values of the parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$
(with the above condition) giving nonisomorphic groups.

**Remarks.**

1. The group $P$ is cyclic iff $\beta=\gamma=\delta=0$.
2. $P$ is split iff $\alpha=\beta$, or $\beta=\gamma$, or $\delta=0$.

This can all be found on page 27 of Hyo-Seob Sim's book
[Metacyclic groups of odd order](https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/136155/2/b18142990_Sim_Hyo-Seob.pdf)
There you can also find a rich bibliography on the subject.